How do I define a Laravel hasOneThrough method for this scenario?
I have an Order model that belongs to a Portfolio model, the Portfolio model belongs to a FinancialGoal model and the FinancialGoal model belongs to a User model.
The order model has this financialGoal method:
public function financialGoal()
{
   return $this->hasOneThrough(FinancialGoal::class, Portfolio::class, 'id', 'id', 
   'portfolio_id', 'financial_goal_id');
}

What could be the reason my definition of a user method isn't giving the expected result:
public function user()
{
   // return $this->financialGoal->user(); // works
   // return $this->financialGoal->belongsTo(User::class); // works 
      return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, FinancialGoal::class, 'id', 'id', 'portfolio_id',
        'user_id'); // returns Attempt to read property "id" on null
}

I would also like to know how to define (orders method) the inverse of this method in the user model, what I have currently throws no error but returns nothing:
public function orders()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Portfolio::class,'financial_goal_id', 
     'portfolio_id', 'id', 'id');
}

This method returns:
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#16085
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}


I always get this mixed up but to help, I simply add x to the column names (e.g. financial_goal_idx, portfolio_idx) and Laravel will throw an error confirming which parameters relate to which columns, from here I usually spot that as always, I'm using the wrong column names.
